# Crystal Report Selection Formula unable to use variable

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I am working on the crystal report and I am having some issues with selection formula as I am not able to use variable in the below code. However if I, mention the string directly then formula is working

Code not working:
Dim tb As String= "104"
CrystalReport. SelectionFormula= "{table1.tableno}= tb"

Above code is not working and giving a message, string field required, however I have already define my variable 'tb' as string.

Below code is working without using variable:
CrystalReport. SelectionFormula= "{table1.tableno}= '104' "

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use parameter fields to pass values from your code to crystal reports, check  [this link](http://vb.net-informations.com/crystal-report/vb.net_crystal_report_parameter_string.htm) it will show you exactly how to do it ..

edited: you would do that like so.. dtt is a datatable here..

```
CrystalReport1.SetDataSource(dtt)
CrystalReport1.SetParameterValue("param", TextBox1.Text)
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = CrystalReport1
CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. However I would like to go through below code. Is it possible? . SelectionFormula= "{table1.tableno}= '104' " How I can use variable here instead of value 104? Do you also have any thing for selection of list values in crystal report?

Comment: Any reason why u want to use selection like that instead of parameter field?

Comment: The only reason for having selection formula is that this is very short. Only thing which stop me, I wanted to do it dynamically, not a fixed value as shown in my example. Everything work fine, only the requirement was to keep the criteria value dynamic instead of having fix. I will try your new code that seems good to my requirement and let you know i face any issue. Thanks for your great help!

Comment: Moreover to this. I would also like to use parameter as a list variable. Suppose, I have stored some values in my list variable. what would be the way to select the data from crystal report for all the list values? eg. how can i select the data for list values like 102, 103, 104, 105 etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should be:

```
Dim tb As String= "104"
CrystalReport.SelectionFormula= "{table1.tableno}='" + tb +"'"
```

Comment: sorry Suraj I forgot the quotation marks.  I've edited, perhaps this will work now.

Comment: Its working now. Thank you for your help. I hope you wouldn't mind to ask you, in case my variable store some list data then what wiuld be the formula in the same manner.